# Smooch android RTL not showing chat script bubbles

Tags: android, right-to-left, smooch

Once the Android system wide language have changed to a RTL (right to left) language like Arabic in my case. The chat stops showing just like this photo.

I'm using smooch latest release and google play services 9.4.0.

[Image of smooch chat with RTL on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNUUs.jpg)

How can I make it work and show chat script like LTR?

Comment: OK. What is the question??

Comment: How can I make it work and show chat script like LTR?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in the latest SDK version ([4.0.7](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-android/releases/tag/4.0.7)) of Smooch

Answer (score 0):

You can control your layouts and widgets in terms of direction (TRL <-> LTR ) by these attributes in layout:

> For more precise control over your app UI in both LTR and RTL mode,
>   Android 4.2 includes the following new APIs to help manage View
>   components:

```
android:layoutDirection
```

Attribute for setting the direction of a component's layout.

```
android:textDirection
```

Attribute for setting the direction of a component's text.

For more, see: http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: You are right, but Smooch have it's own SDK and Activity which I have no control over it

Comment: I see you've filed a bug in the github repo. Thanks for doing so, we'll look into it.

https://github.com/smooch/smooch-android/issues/57